# How to implement if-else statement in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

I am trying to implement an if -else statement in XSLT but my code just doesn't parse.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
  <xsl:variable name="CreatedDate" select="@createDate"/>
  <xsl:variable name="IDAppendedDate" select="2012-01-01" />
  <b>date: <xsl:value-of select="$CreatedDate"/></b> 

  <xsl:if test="$CreatedDate > $IDAppendedDate">
    <h2> mooooooooooooo </h2>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:else>
    <h2> dooooooooooooo </h2>
  </xsl:else>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSL if else condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239308/xsl-if-else-condition)

Answer (score 400, accepted):

You have to reimplement it using `<xsl:choose>` tag:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$CreatedDate > $IDAppendedDate">
    <h2> mooooooooooooo </h2>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <h2> dooooooooooooo </h2>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 84):

If statement is used for checking just one condition quickly. 
When you have multiple options, use `<xsl:choose>` as illustrated below:

```
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$CreatedDate > $IDAppendedDate">
       <h2>mooooooooooooo</h2>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <h2>dooooooooooooo</h2>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
```

Also, you can use multiple `<xsl:when>` tags to express `If .. Else If` or `Switch` patterns as illustrated below:

```
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$CreatedDate > $IDAppendedDate">
       <h2>mooooooooooooo</h2>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="$CreatedDate = $IDAppendedDate">
       <h2>booooooooooooo</h2>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <h2>dooooooooooooo</h2>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
```

The previous example would be equivalent to the pseudocode below:

```
   if ($CreatedDate > $IDAppendedDate)
   {
       output: <h2>mooooooooooooo</h2>
   }
   else if ($CreatedDate = $IDAppendedDate)
   {
       output: <h2>booooooooooooo</h2>
   }
   else
   {
       output: <h2>dooooooooooooo</h2>
   }
```

Comment: Could you please correct the statement below, we all know that if(case > x ) without following {} will only execute 1 following line, i have seen this on many beginners that they write exactly what you have posted here, probably many of them copied 1:1

Comment: By the way, the `if else` condition was just an example or Rather a pseudocode. Well, I consider your concern and I've edited it ..

Answer (score 42):

*If I may offer some suggestions (two years later but hopefully helpful to future readers)*:

- Factor out the common `h2` element.
- Factor out the common `ooooooooooooo` text.
- Be aware of new XPath 2.0 `if/then/else` construct if using XSLT 2.0.

### XSLT 1.0 Solution <sup><sub><sub>(also works with XSLT 2.0)</sub></sub></sup>

```
<h2>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$CreatedDate > $IDAppendedDate">m</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>d</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  ooooooooooooo
</h2>
```

### XSLT 2.0 Solution

```
<h2>
   <xsl:value-of select="if ($CreatedDate > $IDAppendedDate) then 'm' else 'd'"/>
   ooooooooooooo
</h2>
```

Answer (score 4):

Originally from this [blog post](https://aabingunz.com/xsl-if-else/). We can achieve if else by using below code

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="something to test">

    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

So here is what I did

```
<h3>System</h3>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="autoIncludeSystem/autoincludesystem_info/@mdate"> <!-- if attribute exists-->
            <p>
                <dd><table border="1">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>File Name</th>
                            <th>File Size</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>AM/PM</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="autoIncludeSystem/autoincludesystem_info">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" ><xsl:value-of select="@filename"/></td>
                                <td valign="top" ><xsl:value-of select="@filesize"/></td>
                                <td valign="top" ><xsl:value-of select="@mdate"/></td>
                                <td valign="top" ><xsl:value-of select="@mtime"/></td>
                                <td valign="top" ><xsl:value-of select="@ampm"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </dd>
            </p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise> <!-- if attribute does not exists -->
            <dd><pre>
                <xsl:value-of select="autoIncludeSystem"/><br/>
            </pre></dd> <br/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

**My Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward approach is to do a second if-test but with the condition inverted.  This technique is shorter, easier on the eyes, and easier to get right than a choose-when-otherwise nested block:

```
<xsl:variable name="CreatedDate" select="@createDate"/>
     <xsl:variable name="IDAppendedDate" select="2012-01-01" />
     <b>date: <xsl:value-of select="$CreatedDate"/></b> 
     <xsl:if test="$CreatedDate &gt; $IDAppendedDate">
        <h2> mooooooooooooo </h2>
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:if test="$CreatedDate &lt;= $IDAppendedDate">
        <h2> dooooooooooooo </h2>
     </xsl:if>
```

Here's a real-world example of the technique being used in the style-sheet for a government website:  http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/latest_ob.xsl

Comment: Having to remember and make sure that the second `if` test matches the complement of the first one makes any subsequent modification more prone to error.

Comment: I agree, Pal. Also, I think the above example is harder to read, whereas using a `<xsl:choose>` would be far more straightforward, its meaning far more clear.