# if else condition is not working in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying try **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622338/how-to-implement-if-else-statement-in-xslt)** link for `else if` condition but without sucess.

My code is

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="//./ActionParams/@txt_sid = '110'">
    <xsl:for-each select="ext">
      <config type="2" 
              localserver="newxyz.com" 
              liveserver="newxyz.com" 
              httpuri="/etmailregistration/ok/UnsubFrmApp?sendmail=1" 
              params="txt_id,txt_sid" 
              readtimeout="39000" retry="3"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:for-each select="ext">
      <config type="2" 
              localserver="oldxyz.com" 
              liveserver="oldxyz.com" 
              httpuri="/etmailregistration/UnsubFrmApp.aspx?sendmail=1" 
              params="txt_id,txt_sid" 
              readtimeout="39000" 
              retry="3"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

My service call is only newxyz.com

If `txt_sid = 110` then it calls `newxyz.com`
If `txt_sid = 120` then it calls `newxyz.com`, not `oldxyz.com`

Can you please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: You forgot to include your XML as well as the context that the `<xsl:choose>` runs in.

Comment: @Tomalak i have allready add XML in my page

Comment: @RohitAzad No, you haven't. Please see: [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Your test says “if *anywhere in the document,* there is an `ActionParams` element that is not the top-most element and that has an attribute `txt_sid` with a value of `'110'`, …”.

Now, you didn't provide enough input to be sure and you didn't specify what you expected to happen and what you saw instead. But I'm feeling like guessing today and will assume that you didn't want to always check the full document, but only below your current context. Try either using `./ActionParams/@txt_sid='110'` or `.//ActionParams/@txt_sid='110'`, depending on what exactly you are looking for. It's probably a good idea to first think about what you are looking for instead of blindly trying one of these.