# XSLT 1.0 - how to check when condition for string

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to conditional check on the input xml file and place the value.

input xml:

```
<workorder>
    <newwo>1</newwo>
</workorder>
```

If newwo is 1, then I have to set in my output as "NEW" else "OLD"

Expected output is:

```
newwo: "NEW"
```

my xslt is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="NEWWO" />

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/NEWWO">
    <xsl:text>{
      newwo:"
    </xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="NEWWO != '0'">NEW</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>OLD</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>"
    }</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your XSLT attempt (based on your current understanding of XSLT). Also, read : [How to implement if-else statement in XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622338/how-to-implement-if-else-statement-in-xslt)

Comment: You would just use a `<xsl:when>` element to do that.  Without seeing your XSLT (particularly to know which element [workorder or newwo] is the context node when you are working with it), we can't show the correct use of it.

Comment: Sorry guys. Copied the xslt. output i am getting is simply: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of reasons you aren't getting output.

1. The xpaths are case sensitive. `NEWWO` is not going to match `newwo`.
2. You match `/` and then apply-templates to `newwo` (case fixed), but `newwo` doesn't exist at that context. You'll either have to add `*/` or `workorder/` to the apply-templates (like `select="*/newwo"`) or change `/` to `/*` or `/workorder` in the match.
3. You match `/newwo` (case fixed again), but `newwo` is not the root element. Remove the `/`.
4. You do the following test: `test="newwo != '0'"`, but `newwo` is already the current context. Use `.` or `normalize-space()` instead. (If you use `normalize-space()`, be sure to test against a string. (Quote the `1`.))

Here's an updated example.

**XML Input**

```
<workorder>
    <newwo>1</newwo>
</workorder>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="newwo" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="newwo">
    <xsl:text>{&#xA;newwo: "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=".=1">NEW</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>OLD</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>"&#xA;}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
{
newwo: "NEW"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You try it as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  version="1.0">

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/workorder/newwo = 1">
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> newwo:New</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> newwo:Old</xsl:text>                    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```