# Using if-else statement in XSLT for-each

Tags: if-statement, xslt

I have a xslt document. And i want use if statement in this document. My code is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="cbc:ProfileID"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>

    <xsl:if test="cbc:ProfileID='code1'">
        <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="cbc:ProfileID='code2'">
        <xsl:text>B</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
```

I want if returned value is code1 then write A and if returned value is code2 then write B.

How can i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement if-else statement in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622338/how-to-implement-if-else-statement-in-xslt)

Comment: you should post example xml and full code then we can understand and able to answer proper.

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand you are already in the same context by `for-each` so you need to use `.` in if condition like below:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)='code1'">
```

or

```
<xsl:if test=".='code1'">
```

Comment: It's succeded. Thank you very much :)

Comment: please close the question by accepting the answer if it's help you to achive your desire output. Cheers!!!!